# If $\|f\|_\infty=\infty$ implies $f\not\in L_1$?

Tags: integration, measure-theory

Let $f\in L_1=\{f$ measurable $:\|f\|_1=\int_X|f|\,d\mu<\infty\}$, where $\mu$ is a measure finite ($\mu(X)<\infty$).

My doubt is if $\|f\|_\infty=\infty$, then $f\not\in L_1$. If it's the case, then $|f|=\infty$ at a set $E$ such that $\mu(E)>0$ So
$$
\int_X|f|\,d\mu\geq\int_E|f|\,d\mu\geq\int_X\inf_{x\in E}|f|\,d\mu=\inf_{x\in E}|f|\cdot\mu(E)=\infty.
$$
Then, $f\not\in L_1$. It's correct?

Comment: What about $f : x \mapsto \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ on $X=]0,1]$ ?

Comment: $|f|$ need not be infinite on a set of positive measure.

Comment: Thanks, this is useful.

Comment: @Kempa: If $f\in L_1(\mu)$ then $\mu(|f|=\infty)=\mu\bigcap_n\{|f|>n\}\leq\lim_n\mu\big(\{|f|>n\}\big)=\lim_n\frac{\|f\|_1}{n}=0$.
If $f=\infty$ on a set of positive measure, then of course $\|f\|_1=\infty$. Still, functions can be in $L_1(\mu)$ but not in $L_\infty$ regardless of whether the measure is finite or not: $f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\mathbb{1}_{(0,1]}(x)$, $g(x)=\frac{1}{x^2}\mathbb{1}_{[1,\infty)}(x)$